# How to fix it with date format?

Tags: javascript, html, date

In this script it tries to do so that when you choose the date and the given format it shows. Of course, something is wrong with validation . If the "Select date format" option is selected, it will show an error. If you choose the other 2 formats, normally you should do

```js
var nazwamiesiecy = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var nazwadni = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

let input = document.querySelector("input");
let guzik = document.querySelector("button");

guzik.addEventListener("click", () => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let wybranaData = new Date(input.value);

  let format = document.querySelectorAll("select").value
  let opcja1 = document.querySelectorAll("option")[0].value
  let opcja2 = document.querySelectorAll("option")[1].value
  let opcja3 = document.querySelectorAll("option")[2].value

  if (!input.value) {
    alert("Enter the date");
    return;
  }

  if (!opcja1) {
    alert("Enter the date format")
    return;
  }

  if (!opcja2) {
    document.getElementById("dataa").innerHTML = wybranaData.getDate() + " " + nazwamiesiecy[wybranaData.getMonth()] + " " + wybranaData.getFullYear().toString() + " roku";
    return;
  }

  if (!opcja3) {
    document.getElementById("dataaa").innerHTML = wybranaData.getDate() + "." + wybranaData.getMonth() + "." + wybranaData.getFullYear().toString();
    return;
  }
})
```

```html
<form name="">
  <div>
    <label for="txtnum1">Date: </label>
    <input type="date" name="txtnum1" id="txtnum1">
  </div>

  <label for="sztos">Date format: </label>
  <select name="sztos" id="sztos">
    <option value="">Choose a date format</option>
    <option value="op">12/04/2000</option>
    <option value="xd">12 April 2000</option>
  </select>


  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>

  <div id="dataa"></div>
  <div id="dataaa"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your opcja tests are wrong,
- querySelectorAll returns a nodeList Just test the querySelector("select").value
- your format is with dots, not slashes
- you are not passing the event in the event listener
- no need to use toString on numbers when you concatenate

```js
var nazwamiesiecy = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var nazwadni = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

let input = document.querySelector("input");
let guzik = document.querySelector("button");
let dataa = document.getElementById("dataa")
guzik.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!input.value) {
    alert("Enter the date");
    return;
  }

  let format = document.querySelector("select").value

  if (!format) {
    alert("Enter the date format")
    return;
  }

  let wybranaData = new Date(input.value);
  
  let dateString = "";
  if (format === "xd") {
    dateString = wybranaData.getDate() + " " + nazwamiesiecy[wybranaData.getMonth()] + " " + wybranaData.getFullYear() + " roku";
  } else if (format === "op") {
    dateString = wybranaData.getDate() + "/" + wybranaData.getMonth() + "/" + wybranaData.getFullYear();
  }
  dataa.innerHTML = dateString;
})
```

```html
<form name="">
  <div>
    <label for="txtnum1">Date: </label>
    <input type="date" name="txtnum1" id="txtnum1">
  </div>
  <label for="sztos">Date format: </label>
  <select name="sztos" id="sztos">
    <option value="">Choose a date format</option>
    <option value="op">dd/mm/yyyy</option>
    <option value="xd">dd MMMMMM yyyy</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
  <div id="dataa"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: and how to do that when you click 2 options, having already 1, that one option appears instead of 2

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: that if I already format one date format and I list it and click the second one, then the first one will disappear, so that 2 will not be displayed

Comment: Don't have two outputs. Remove `<div id="dataaa"></div>` and change `document.getElementById("dataaa")` to `document.getElementById("dataa")`